# How to use py. command in matlab

Tags: python, matlab

I have a python function that receives 4 arrays. when trying to call the function from matlab, i get the error:"Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object". anyone knows how should i use the py. command to call python?

My code is: addpath C:\Python27

px = num2str(rand(2,10));

py = num2str(rand(2,10));

cx = num2str(rand(2,10));

cy = num2str(rand(2,10));

py."MyPythonCode.main(px,py,cx,cy)"

Comment: You’ve created a variable `py` that is shadowing the Python object.

Comment: I see, so how do I use the python object?

Comment: Use a different name for the variable instead of `py`!

Comment: See these pages for more information: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-python.html